RPM cannot find dependency located inside the package
I made my own RPM package. The package contains:

./bin/my_binary (depends on my_lib.so)
./bin/lib/my_lib.so
other files

Then I'm trying to install it and have error:
rpm -Uhv my_rpm_name.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        my_lib.so()(64bit) is needed by my_rpm_name

But if I use --nodeps option everything installed and works well.
Looks like RPM can't see that dependency of my_binary (my_lib.so) is located inside. How can I fix it?

Typically you would package the library separately. Otherwise, why not just statically link it into the executable?

This is because you did not put the library in standard path (/lib). Therefore standard generator of automatic provides failed to find it and therefore did not generated the provides.
You can learn more in Fedora Packaging Guidelines in library section https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/#_shared_libraries
